# Avoiding duplication of validation code at Javascript frontend and Java backend?

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, validation

We are having a standard web application, and front-end is using Angular, back-end is written in Java 7. What I noticed, is that we get a lot of duplicating code. That is, validation is performed client-side by angular, but I cannot trust him completely, since the user can disable client-side validation and simply submit a post query to server.

Therefore, I have to repeat the same validation logic at server side in Java. This is quite tedious, but I don't know how to avoid that. Perhaps I can write some parts of back-end with a javascript framework (suppose it's Node.js), that could use the same validation library as the front-end, and make Java back-end  interact with node.js? What is the best approach in order to solve this problem?

Comment: That would mean you have 2 backends?
Ever thought of stuff like microservices?

Comment: Not sure about that. Maybe Java could just somehow use javascript libraries in order to perform the validation? Maybe you could just generate code for javascript validation based on back end validation code, or vice versa?

Comment: Java has nothing to do with Javascript, really. Only do minimal checks on the frontend (basic type/length validation) and do the database checks and more in-depth checks in the backend.

Comment: I agree with Andrius, all validation must be conducted on server side, except some basic things

Comment: @Andrius, from technical point of view completely agree - it is cheaper to code all validation on backend side, but thanks to validations on frontend side you can provide more seamless UX for user. Thus need to share logic is reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java can run JavaScript code and other dynamic scripting languages. In Java 7 the JavaScript ScriptEngine is called Rhino, and in Java 8 is called Nashorn.

The Oracle Java Scripting Programmer's Guide for Java 7:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

Maybe you can write pure JavaScript in js files that you can place in the BackEnd to serve for the client and execute into the server too.

Answer (score 0):

[AngularBeans](https://github.com/bessemHmidi/AngularBeans) framework is allows you to define BeanValidation on java side and transforms to angular form validation so code is not duplicated. Look at example of usage in [this](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/angularbeans-a-fresh-new-take-on-angularjs-and-javaee/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Define validation rules as data in a JSON format, for example, and expose them through an endpoint in the same API which exposes your data. Now the validation rules are public and can be used by any other service to validate the data using some library that can parse the rules and accept/reject the submitted data (i.e. from a form).

Comment: Do you have any example of some framework or rule format for that?

Comment: [JSON-Schema](https://www.json-schema.org/) is a nice and fairly comprehensive declarative validation format. In spite of the fact that it's declarative, you can get quite fancy -- regex validation of keys and values, min/max, enums, type classes, discriminated unions, dependencies, etc.